# Как запретить использование символов ".;:"*()[]{}!@#$%^&<>" при написании в bat

Tags: cmd, bat

Нужно в команде

```
set /p name=Name:
```

запретить использование всех символов кроме строчных прописных и цифр, чтобы при нажатии на "=" он не ввелся а цифра "1" ввелась

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off echo Ввод [0-9]:& set /p z= echo %z%|>nul findstr /rc:"^[0-9][0-9]*$" && (echo %z%) || (echo Недопустимый символ) pause
```

Пробуй так, только в регулярке поставь свои ограничения

Comment: это понятно, у меня такой же код но как подправить регулярку. как запретить  пробел кавычки скобки и треугольные выдиления.

Answer (score 0):

Вот ответ на мой вопрос. При написании спецсимволов будет ошибка, до тех пор, не будут введены нормальные символы. Но все равно не рекомендуется использовать спецсимволы, особенно "<" ">" из-за структуры cmd.

```
@echo off
SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
rem Chcp 866 >nul
title %~dp0
cd /d "%~dp0"

:1

set /p newname=Novoe imya: 

echo %newname%|>nul findstr /rc:"^[A-Z0-9a-z][A-Z0-9a-z]*$" && (
echo.
) || (
echo.
echo Nedopustimuij simvol
echo.
) && (
goto 1

echo %newname%

pause
exit /B
```